# How much necromancy is required for the Bushido hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012, necromancer-badge

The Bushido hat is just called the Necromancer hat.  Does anyone know its exact requirements?  Is it identical to a Necromancer badge in all ways, or is it only 3 votes not 5, or some different ancientness?

Comment: I'd be surprised if it is any different to the requirements for the badge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, this is a ***seekrit*** hat, so I shouldn't tell you!

> That said, Oded is right: earn the Necromancer badge and that should trigger this hat. Maybe. It's worth a shot. :D

Comment: Hats are odd.  The repcap that triggered my jester’s hat cannot be used for the monarch hat, because I got downpipped below 200 for my first repcap, but had already gotten the jester hat. It isn’t just hitting the repcap on five different days; you have to close out the day that way, too.